# Hoffman and Kunze, Linear Algebra Chapter 2 exercise 3.8

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be the space of $2\times 2$ matrices over $F.$ Find a basis $\{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4,\}$ for $V$ such that $A_j^2=A_j,$ for each $j.$

Let $X=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3&x_4\end{bmatrix}.$ We want  $X^2=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3&x_4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3&x_4\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_2x_3+x_1^2 & x_2(x_1+x_4)\\x_3(x_1+x_4)&x_2x_3+x_4^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1 & x_2\\x_3&x_4\end{bmatrix}.$

Looking at the equations I wrote these vectors $\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 &0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\}$ as the basis.

> I want to arrive at the general vectors just by solving those equations rather than guessing some particular solutions. Can you show me how to go about obtaining the general solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by general solution?

Comment: Well, I meant to say that some solution matrices like $\begin{bmatrix}a & 0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: which would hold in general for any constants that I plug in

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) on idempotent matrices for a discussion on the real $2 \times 2$ case. Since the field $F$ is arbitrary in your question, the only elements of the field that you can explicitly write down are $0$ and $1$, so it is best to search for an example using just these elements, as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

*From the comments above.*

---

See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) on idempotent matrices for a discussion on the real $2 \times 2$ case. Since the field $F$ is arbitrary in your question, the only elements of the field that you can explicitly write down are $0$ and $1$, so it is best to search for an example using just these elements, as you have done.